# How to parse a local tsv variable on d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently have the following:

```
d3.tsv(filename, function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.outside = +d.outside;
        d.house = +d.house;
});
```

That gets a tsv file and processes it with no issues. What I would like to do is to replace "filename" (which is a file) with a variable (such a string containing text in tsv format). How can I easily do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`d3.tsv.parse()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-tsv_parse) for this, e.g.

```
var data = d3.tsv.parse(string);
```

Comment: This is what the debugger shows:

`var contents='date  outside house
20140328144003       5.6            18.1
20140328143003       5.4            18.1
20140328071003       10.3           18.6
';
var data = d3.tsv.parse(contents);`

The contents variable has the right data, but I get "Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL". Ideally, after fixing this issue, I would like to parse the data like this (being parse date a function I created):

`data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.outside = +d.outside;
        d.house = +d.house;`

Comment: Could you post a reproducible example please on something like jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tFCnb/ can't really run it without data, etc. The thing is, line 60, I believe, is the one giving problems. If I substitute content with a filename and uncomment the lines under line 60, everything works fine.

Comment: Well what does `content` looks like? It works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/B7MHd/

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in your jsfiddle. Did you see my working example?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for example, you can obtain the string from a fetch query and then transform it to text so that later can be parsed with D3.js.

This is once loaded in your browser: https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js

```js
var data = await fetch('/mytsv.tsv');
var mytsvstr = await data.text();
var tsvdata = await d3.tsvParse(mytsvstr);
```

Source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/d3js/d3js_delimiterseparated_values_api.htm